# C# intra-app Generic Pub/Sub subset pattern

Tags: c#, publish-subscribe

I'm not entirely sure of the correct terminology for what I'm looking for, so please bear with me.  In the application I am maintaining, we have a standard PubSub implementation for getting data from several different publishers into the application.  We have a "service" for subscribing to the data which handles the PubSub negotiation, and different kinds of data have different services (e.g. Products, Orders, Vendors, etc).  These services generally notify the application of messages via a plain vanilla .NET event.

However not all parts of the application are interested in all of the events.  For example, some places might only be interest in Products A, B, and C, while another place in the app wants Products B, D, and E, and what is wanted is generally driven by user input.  What ends up happening then is that in every single location in the app, a handler is added to the service's event and that handler filters out unwanted events based upon other code that sets up the filter based on the user input.  Not surprisingly, the code for filtering and setting up the filter is basically the same everywhere.

This seems like a great place for a generic PubSub set of objects to sit between the service and the places wanting the data.  I can set up concrete versions of the objects for each data scenario as needed and add them to the services for the various places in the app to consume.  Not wanting to reinvent the wheel, I've been googling PubSub and the closest thing I can find to this is Topics, but those don't fit in this scenario, because it would require setting up a topic for every single product.

Are there any resources of which anyone knows concering this?  I'm working in C#, but I can adapt from other languages if needed.  The main requirement is that this can't be a separate service or process, such as WCF; it needs to reside in the application and use the existing infrastructure, presumably by attaching to the service's event and then notify subscribers that way.  Also of concern is the fact that this app is heavily multithreaded, so a bent towards thread-safety would be helpful, though I can adapt to that as needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would look at DDS products (data distribution services) such as RTI. they offer all you require and much more. 
see:
http://www.rti.com/products/dds/

Comment: @aaronburro , have you looked at DDS? does it meet your needs?

Comment: I looked at that, but that is far and away a much heavier solution than I could use.  A separate service to handle all of this data would require a complete rewrite of the existing company messaging infrastructure, and that's not feasible, unless I am missing something.  I appreciate the suggestion, though.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to acheive what you want with a 3'rd party solution residing in your application without changing your infrastructure API and implemntation. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

hmm..not sure if i understand correctly. how about something like this? usage pattern

```
public void handleui(dynamic s)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
                                              {
                                                  btn1.Content = s.ToString();
                                              });
}
Globals.Events["error"] += msg=> Console.WriteLine(msg);//logger perhaps
Globals.Events["productb"] += handleui;//sub
Globals.Events["productb"] -= handleui;//unsub    
Globals.Events["productb"].Send("productbdata");//raise the event or publish to productb channel subscribers
Globals.Events.Send("broadcast?");
```

i would imagine you might do a single filter which simply send all events to Events["producta"], Events["productb"] , Events["productc"]  etc. and the parts can just sub/unsub when they want it.

implementation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;


public class Globals
{
    public static MsgBus Events = new MsgBus();
}

public class MsgBus
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<dynamic, MsgChannel> channels = new ConcurrentDictionary<dynamic, MsgChannel>();

    public MsgChannel this[dynamic channel]
    {
        set { channels[channel] = value; }
        get
        {
            var ch = (MsgChannel)channels.GetOrAdd(channel, new MsgChannel());
            return ch;
        }
    }

    private MsgChannel broadcast = new MsgChannel();
    public void Send(dynamic msg)
    {
        broadcast.Send(msg);
    }

    public static MsgBus operator +(MsgBus left, Action<dynamic> right)
    {
        left.broadcast += right;
        return left;
    }

    public static MsgBus operator -(MsgBus left, Action<dynamic> right)
    {
        left.broadcast -= right;
        return left;
    }
}

public class MsgChannel
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<Action<dynamic>, int> observers = new ConcurrentDictionary<Action<dynamic>, int>();
    public void Send(dynamic msg)
    {
        foreach (var observer in observers)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < observer.Value; i++)
            {
                observer.Key.Invoke(msg);
            }
        }
    }
    public static MsgChannel operator +(MsgChannel left, Action<dynamic> right)
    {

        if (!left.observers.ContainsKey(right))
        {
            left.observers.GetOrAdd(right, 0);
        }

        left.observers[right]++;
        return left;
    }

    public static MsgChannel operator -(MsgChannel left, Action<dynamic> right)
    {
        if (left.observers.ContainsKey(right) &&
            left.observers[right] > 0)
        {
            left.observers[right]--;
            int dummy;
            if (left.observers[right] <= 0) left.observers.TryRemove(right, out dummy);
        }

        return left;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but it's not really what I'm aiming for.  This seems to allow reuse of known, possibly pre-formed event handlers among several listeners for the exact same event, but that's not the problem I'm trying to solve.  I'm trying to avoid writing the same code _for different events_ whose sole purpose is to figure out if the event handler should continue processing the event.  A perfect world is that I can give the event a list of criteria of stuff I'm actually interested in and the event will only give me stuff that matches that criteria.